# What ({!Lookup.minorType == country}) means in JAPE for GATE

Tags: nlp, gate

While I am going through JAPE(GATE) learning resources, came across below peace of JAPE rule which is eliminating the(bold formatted) text from becoming the annotation.

JAPE Rule: ({!Lookup.minorType == country})

Text: **University of Sheffield** US

What exactly the meaning of the above statement? My quick interpretation is **minorType** shouldn't be equal to type **country**. But if that is true why the below statements are not working in the same way as above?

({Lookup.minorType != country})

({Lookup.minorType == !country})

Any helpful links to understand LHS and RHS rule syntaxes in detailed manner would be appreciated.

Comment: These are three completely different operators with different meanings and semantics. This is a good question, maybe I'll find some time for an answer later...

Comment: @dedek looks like theoretically there is no much difference among all the three scenario's mentioned in the question. I found some explanation on why they are not practically same and added it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, found explanation by myself at the below link.

https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:jape:negation

```
Rule: SurnameNotStartingWithDe  
(  
 {Surname, !Token.string ==~ "[Dd]e"}  
):name  
-->  
 :name.NotDe = {}
```

This would match any Surname annotation that does not start at the same place as a Token with the string ‘de’ or ‘De’. Note that this is subtly diﬀerent from `{Surname, Token.string !=~ "[Dd]e"}`, as the second form requires a Token annotation to be present, whereas the ﬁrst form (!Token...) will match if there is no Token annotation at all at this location.

As per the example in the question, University of Sheffield need to be a Lookup annotation(which is actually not) to make it work in all three different scenarios.

Comment: Great! Perfect answer! The last IMO missing bit is `({Lookup.minorType == !country})`. What `!country` means here? Is it some boolean expression? Or is it even syntactically correct?